# Multi tenant DB management tool

Tags: postgresql, mariadb

I am working towards setting up a new services architecture for a SaaS product and it needs to have a multi-tenant setup.

Currently the DB setup is using MariaDB, but I am also looking into potentially using Postgres.

In addition to the set-up of the DB cluster, migration tools (currently thinking flyway but open to suggestions), I am in need of a tenant manager.

The initial idea was to make a separate custom service, which manages creation of the tenant DBs and doing backups/ restores etc.. but I am wondering if there is some tool out there which can do at-least part of that job and I can just integrate with that?

Is there a tool which can help manage creation/ deletion of schemas/DBs in a multi-tenant setup